# JavaScript not running on Local HTML Page (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

This is just a general problem, which is probably going to be closed. This is different than other already existing questions.

When I try to run *any* JavaScript in a local HTML page, it doesn't work. This isn't a problem with improperly coded JavaScript (or HTML/CSS). When I grab a standalone JavaScript example (that doesn't require an external library or have any external references) from any coding site and put it in a local HTML, or any page in chrome, it won't work. It always works on the original site, so it's not a problem with the JavaScript itself. The same is true when I use examples that provide the entire HTML code.

Simple examples that use onclick like this work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

But anything with a `<script>` tag doesn't:

```js
function myFunction(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3);
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation and returns the result:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: How **exactly** are you including the JavaScript on your page? Are you including it on the index itself, in `<script>` tags? Are you loading it via an external JavaScript file (such as `script.js`)? Have you ensured that you haven't accidentally disabled JavaScript in your browser? Are you getting any errors in the F12 Developer Tools console?

Comment: If this is only happening on Chrome, make sure javascript has not been disabled at the browser level.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am including the JavaScript directly (no external references) in the HTML using a <script> tag. I do have JavaScript enabled in my settings and have not touched any JavaScript settings in the Chrome Flags. I don't see anything in the console either.

Comment: UPDATE: Resetting my Chrome flags actually fixed this, through I'm not actually sure which one broke it. I've re-enabled the flags I use, but the JavaScript still works, so something must've been enabled by accident.